# Django TemplateError when using if...else block inside for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following as part of my django template:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page.has_previous %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'main:stream_detail' stream_id=stream.id %}?p={{page.next_page_number}}" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="disabled" aria-label="previous"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
        (% if i == page.number %}
        <li class="active">{{i}} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'main:stream_detail' stream_id=stream.id %}?p={{i}}">{{i}}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if page.has_next %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'main:stream_detail' stream_id=stream.id %}?p={{page.next_page_number}}" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="disabled" aria-label="next"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

> Invalid block tag on line 26: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Line 26 corresponds to the `{% else %}` clause inside the `{% for %}` loop. As fas as I can tell, this else clause correctly matches up with the if statement, but the template parser seems to expect a clause to match the for loop there.

Comment: Even if you seem to have the correct `if else` match up in this block, the error might still blow up if you have errors in other sections. What I suggest to debug this is to remove the `<nav>` block totally and add the code back little by little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error with the `if` tag in the `for` loop:

```
(% if
```

...should be

```
{% if
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `'('` instead of `'{'` on line `(% if i == page.number %}`